# How do I center the forms without moving the text before the form?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a form that works with PHP, it looks good so far but I want them to line up in the center. Now it centers the whole thing with the text before the forms in the middle.

I wanted to move the forms to the middle, they currently are centered in the middle but not totally as I wanted them to be. I want only the forms themselves to line up, but I haven't been able to find any code that does this.

```css
form { 
  display: inline-block; 
  text-align: left; 
}

input[type=text], select {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=email], select {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  position:static;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #c29bb8;
}
```

```html
<form action="submitform.php" method="post">
  <label for="voornaam">Voornaam:</label>
  <input type="text" id="voornaam" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier je voornaam in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="tussenvoegsel">Tussenvoegsel:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tussenvoegsel" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier eventueel een tussenvoegsel in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="achternaam">Achternaam:</label>
  <input type="text" id="achternaam" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier je achternaam in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier je e-mail in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="review">Review:</label>
  <textarea id="review" name="review"></textarea><br><br>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Verstuur">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add margin-left and margin-right and set them to auto:

```css
form { 
  width: fit-content;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  text-align: left; 
}

input[type=text], select {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=email], select {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

textarea {
  resize: none;
  position:static;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: pink;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #c29bb8;
}
```

```html
<form action="submitform.php" method="post">
  <label for="voornaam">Voornaam:</label>
  <input type="text" id="voornaam" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier je voornaam in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="tussenvoegsel">Tussenvoegsel:</label>
  <input type="text" id="tussenvoegsel" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier eventueel een tussenvoegsel in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="achternaam">Achternaam:</label>
  <input type="text" id="achternaam" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier je achternaam in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="mail">E-mail:</label>
  <input type="email" id="mail" onfocus="this.value=''" value="Vul hier je e-mail in..."><br><br>
  
  <label for="review">Review:</label>
  <textarea id="review" name="review"></textarea><br><br>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Verstuur">
</form>
```

Comment: In addition, you can set the margin area on all four sides using 2-value syntax. For example, `margin: 0 auto;`. The first value represents the vertical, that is top and bottom, edges, the second the horizontal ones, that is the left and right ones.